# How to add download button to external image on our site

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, download

I have a external url image attached with  tags in my page. So i tried all methods to add download button to image.

I have added download attribute but instead of downloading file the button taken me to image file url in new windows or same window.

So please tell me best way to add download button which will give facility of download on one click.

Any Php or js code that worked for you ?

**Note/Edit :- Suppose It Is My Page (http://manvik2.sg-host.com/m.php) So If This Generate Tool One Image Every Time. So I Want To Add Download Button Which Work On All Images**

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a link tag around your image in the HTML :

```
<a href="link/to/image.jpg" download="name-of-image">
    <img src="link/to/image.jpg" alt="your-image" />
</a>
```

Comment: then how we can add a button type link ? because it doesn;t have any text.

Comment: Download Not working in this way also. Only Opening Link In New Tab/Same Tab

Comment: please note that it's a external image which i attached to mine page. so url be like - https://example.com/image.jpg

Comment: You can put the external link into your _href_ attribute.

Comment: i know man ! leave it, focus on the downloading problem

Comment: I tried this but not working as i told you before.....   <a href="https://example.com/image.jpg" download="name-of-image"><img src="https://example.com/image.jpg">
</a>

Comment: download attribute won't work for remote/offsite files

Answer (score -1):

Hi there you can't do it with pure html download attributes.

I don't see clearly how can we do it with js.

For a php solution you will need to curl url of your image and put the image in your server with the same domain name, then you can use the download attributes and it will work

EDIT:
For the php edition i can be that :
you need to create a `files/` folder  first

```
<?php
function grab_image($url,$saveto){
    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0); // <-- don't forget this
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0); // <-- and this
    $raw=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
}

$link = "https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81tISKde7HL._AC_SL1500_.jpg"; // your link 
$temp_match;
preg_match('/(?=\w+\.\w{3,4}$).+/',$link,$temp_match); // get the filename from url return an array

$file_name = $temp_match[0]; //get the name from the array

$path= ('./files/'.$file_name); // create path 
grab_image($link,$path);


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="<?= $path ?>" download="<?=$file_name?>">download</a>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i told before that download attribute not working sir. #I have added download attribute but instead of downloading file the button taken me to image file url in new windows or same window.

Comment: Please Elaborate PHP Solution, Because it is our last hope.

Comment: would be a better UX if CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION was implemented to feed the content to the user not write it to file first. also disabling CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER and the other one is a security risk

Comment: That's right for the ssl, it was a rapid copy past from an code i had uni. First time I saw CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, i will check, thank's for the advice

Comment: @ThéaD your solution can handel lots of external images. ?

Comment: Please See My Edited Question For More Detail

Comment: So your php file create the iamge ?